# Is there any way to zoomout and zoomin force layout in center d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to zoomin and zoomout force layout in the center of the screen. 
Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/).

When I zoom in, zoom out and pan, the layout it takes the mouse points and zooming off of the screen. what I need is it always in center when I zoom in and zoom out even after pan the layout.

```
 function zoomed() {
     container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean set the center of zoom? If so then add the `.center([width/2, height/2])` to initialisation of the zoom behaviour `var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().center([width/2, height/2])`

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/6226534

Check that link. Next time i recommend researching the question before hand.

Main piece of code needed :

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .center([width / 2, height / 2]) //this is what zooms around center
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Comment: call this from your background svg element so svg.call(zoom); but make sure you put the zoom variable above the call otherwise you will not find it

Comment: please check this link i have added center http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/237/      but when i pan the layout its doesn't comes to center.

Comment: fekkyDev is that you ? or you using someone elses jsfiddle ?

Comment: and it does zoom from center. are you asking that when you zoom you want the actual force layout to be centered ?

Comment: Please pan(drag) the layout and try to zoom.

Comment: it works fine, it zooms from the center of the SVG which is what youve asked for